# I want to restart my application on restart of the system

Tags: c++, winapi

I use [GetModuleFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683197.aspx) to get the absolute path to my application, open the `RunOnce` registry key using [RegOpenKeyEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724897.aspx) and set a value using [RegSetValueEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724923.aspx).

```
if (RegOpenKeyEx (HKEY_CURRENT_USER, 
"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\RunOnce",0, KEY_SET_VALUE, &hk1) == ERROR_SUCCESS) 

{ 
    RegSetValueEx(hk1, // subkey handle 
                  "", // value name 
                  0, // must be zero 
                  REG_SZ, // value type 
                  (LPBYTE) &path, sizeof(DWORD)); // length of value data    
    RegCloseKey(hk1); 
}
```

However my application does not start after a system restart.

Comment: You need to edit your question and put in the code you pasted in the comment below - I had a feeling you were asking something about the registry side of this rather than how to start an app on restart specifically

Comment: I did it and reformatted a bit you may need to review it to make sure it says what you want...

Answer (score 3):

There are a few methods:

- Place your application in your start-up folder. This is a very easy method. When your system (PC) will be restarted, the application will get started (You need to login for this);
- Use windows task planner;
- Make the application an [service](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/251192).

I prefer the last option if it always needs to run. But you will need to add [service handling](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/CppWindowsService-cacf4948).

Comment: @Paul, Why is the length of your string data the size of a dword?

Comment: what it should be? , iam a beginner please help.

Comment: @Paul, *The size of the information pointed to by the lpData parameter, in bytes. If the data is of type REG_SZ, REG_EXPAND_SZ, or REG_MULTI_SZ, cbData must include the size of the terminating null character or characters.* That means the size of your path string including the null.

Comment: how should i specify it then, if my path is having 10 charachters?

Comment: @Paul, `10 * sizeof(char_type)`, where `char_type` is the type of character your string is composed of. That assumes you included the null character in those 10.

Comment: @chris the `path` variable is returned from Getmodulefilename, any problem ? Is there any other mistakes other than the size dword?

Comment: @Paul, You can use `strlen` to get the length then. I don't see anything else, but I barely ever use the registry API, so my eye might be a little bit untrained for spotting mistakes with it.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a task using Task Scheduler to run your application when the computer starts.

1. Open Task Scheduler by clicking the Start button , clicking Control Panel, clicking System and Security, clicking Administrative Tools, and then double-clicking Task Scheduler.‌   If you're prompted for an administrator password or confirmation, type the password or provide confirmation.
2. Click the Action menu, and then click Create Basic Task.
3. Type a name for the task and an optional description, and then click Next.
4. Click When the computer starts, and then click Next.
5. To schedule a program to start automatically, click Start a program, and then click Next.
6. Click Browse to find the program you want to start, and then click Next.
7. Select the Open the Properties dialog for this task when I click Finish check box and click Finish.
8. In the Properties dialog box, select Run whether user is logged on or not, and then click OK

Source:

[Windows 7 - Schedule a task](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/schedule-a-task)

PS: You must be logged on as an administrator to perform these steps

Comment: [This page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446817(v=vs.85).aspx) should help if you wanted to do it programmatically.

Comment: What do you mean by `"platform independent code"`? The title of your question is misleading: `"I want to restart my application on restart of the system"`

Comment: @Paul, I think you mean platform-dependent. You tagged it with `winapi` and are using winapi functions, which are most definitely not platform-independent.

Comment: @chris I admit, what i meant was it should work in all windows os.

Comment: @Paul, Ah, well, you can look at the documentation for that. Down at the bottom with the library and header is the minimum supported operating system. The ones that have stopped being applicable have pretty obvious notes tagged onto them.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of things to keep in mind when using the solution you opted for:

- The application does not start when the system starts but rather when the current user logs on.
- If you write to the `RunOnce` key the operation will be performed only once. If you want your application to always start when the user logs on you should instead use the `Run` key.

In addition to the above, if you want to create a value you will have to give it a name. From the documentation of the `lpValueName` parameter for [RegSetValueEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724923.aspx):

> If `lpValueName` is `NULL` or an empty string, `""`, the function sets the type and data for the key's unnamed or default value.

The default (unnamed) value is the one that shows up as `(Default)` when using regedit. To get this to work you will have to provide a name for the value. This should be unique so that it does not conflict with other values under that key.

On a less technical note, implementing an auto-start feature for an application should only be done after thorough consideration.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the wrong parameter values to `RegSetValueEx()`.  You need to use it like this instead:

```
TCHAR path[MAX_PATH+1] = {0}
GetModuleFileName(NULL, path, MAX_PATH);

if (RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, TEXT("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\RunOnce"), 0, KEY_SET_VALUE, &hk1) == ERROR_SUCCESS) 
{ 
    RegSetValueEx(hk1, // subkey handle 
                  TEXT("MyApp"), // value name 
                  0, // must be zero 
                  REG_SZ, // value type 
                  (LPBYTE) path,
                  (lstrlen(path)+1) * sizeof(TCHAR)); // length of value data, in bytes
    RegCloseKey(hk1); 
}
```